# Variation of Delta function integrated

Tags: calculus, fourier-analysis, distribution-theory

We all know:
 $$\int_0^\infty \delta(y) dy = 1.$$

How about
 $$\int_{-\infty}^\infty y\delta(y) dy .$$

The solution of this is $0$. I have no idea how to get this.

thx,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's the definition only. In general it is

$$\int_{-\infty}^\infty f(y) \delta (y)dy = f(0)$$

Now put $f(y) = y$.